# C# Win Form : How to pass values to window form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know how to open a window that I created myself but when I want to code in it I can't access any of my public methods in my form1 or int's or class arrays.

I want to make a combat report and I want to result the kills and death's report in another window so I need to pass some int value's but I don't know how.
Any help for me?

Comment: Could you not use some central class that suplies both forms with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constructor something like this...

```
public void Form2(string name, int age)
{

   InitializeComponent(); //this is default

   this._name = name;

   this._age = age;

}
```

Then we you show it would go something like this.

```
Form2 myNewForm = new Form2("Jimmy", 33); 

myNewForm .Show();
```

Does this help?

Comment: Yeah I will try this out and let you know if it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you have data that you want to access from multiple places, you collect it in a separate type (aka class). Like this:

```
public class MyData {
   public int Kills;
   public int Deaths;
}
```

Then you can create an instance of this class wherever you want:

```
var myData = new MyData();
```

Then you can populate the members of that instance and also pass the whole instance to other forms.

You can pass data from one form to another in the constructor of the form as shown by daeden's answer.

Comment: My classes can be accessed by the other form but not the filled class array's so that was what I was looking for.